# Why do I get 400 Bad Request header on a thin ruby website hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, heroku, thin

I look after www.lesscss.org. The source is here https://github.com/cloudhead/lesscss.org.

This is a thin web application and runs on heroku. Accessing the website in a browser is fine.

We have had a bug that curl -I lesscss.org gives a 400 request - https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1232

and it does

```
$ curl -I lesscss.org
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 01:15:50 GMT
Connection: close
```

I've done alot of searching and haven't found a reason why or how to rectify the above.. shouldn't it be a 302 redirect or a 200 ok?

[Edit]

with verbose option

```
$ curl -Iv http://www.lesscss.org
* About to connect() to www.lesscss.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 107.21.106.77...
* 0x8001f140 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80057408; line 1032 (connection #0)
* Connected to www.lesscss.org (107.21.106.77) port 80 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x80057408; line 1151 (connection #0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.lesscss.org
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80057408; line 1236 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80057408; line 1352 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80057408; line 1363 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx
Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2013 09:34:37 GMT
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2013 09:34:37 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x80057408; line 1533 (connection #0)
* Connection #0 to host www.lesscss.org left intact
* Expire cleared
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toto engine that you're using has [this line](https://github.com/cloudhead/toto/blob/master/lib/toto.rb#L333) in it:

```
return [400, {}, []] unless @request.get?
```

So anything that is not a get will result in a 400. Toto could probably afford to allow head requests through (and combine with Rack::Head to drop request bodies on the floor if needed)

Answer (score 0):

With `-I` you're making `HEAD` requests and not `GET`. Remove the `-I` flag and it will work. You can see how it works with the `-v` flag:

```
curl -Iv lesscss.org
```

Comment: Ok, that helps a bit.. but should we just not support HEAD requests? Is this normal? Or is there a way to switch them on..?

Comment: @LukePage this is not normal. For example, sphinx check links from my docs:

```
(line  10) http://www.postgresql.org - working
(line  15) http://lesscss.org - broken: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
(line  12) http://www.mongodb.org - working
(line  14) http://memcached.org - working
(line  28) https://aur.archlinux.org - working
(line  66) http://packages.debian.org/experimental/libzmq3 - working
(line  98) https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager - working
(line  66) http://packages.debian.org/experimental/libzmq3-dev - working
```